# How do I add elements to two different arrays inside of a loop based on parameters without using the STL?

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm very new to C++, so please let me know if there is an easier way to accomplish what I'm trying to do.

Basically I am checking for two different types of input commands on the command line. If the user enters a C followed by an integer(1 in this case) (I don't need error checking) its supposed to add "C 1" to my first array. If they type A 1 2 400 then it supposed to add that to a second array.

In java I would simply type

```
if (input.contains("c")){
cityArray.add(input)

else if (input.contains ("a"){
routeArray.add(input)
    }
```

or something along those lines.

Here is what I have in C++

```
while(loopCheck == false )
  {
  cout << "Please Enter A Command:> "  << endl;

  cin >> Input;

  if((cin >> c) ){

  cout << "Citys: " << city[] << endl;
  }
  if (cin == " "){
      loopCheck = true;
  }
```

}

Comment: Why don't you want to use the STL?

Comment: I'm not allowed to use the STL for the class I'm in.

Comment: We have no idea what data types you are using, You gave a semi explanation of your requirements, and the way the question is worded it looks like your code works and you want suggestions to make it better which is better suited to Code Review and not Stack Overflow

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I don't understand your question. That looks like perfectly good code to me.

Comment: Questions that can be interpreted as "help me with my homework" frequently get downvoted depending on how much effort appears to have been put into the work. (I'm not saying that's fair, just answering your question about why)

Comment: The C++ code you've provided doesn't seem to even attempt to do anything vaguely similar to the Java code you provided. What do you really want to accomplish?

Comment: @NathanOliver Thank you, I'm not exactly sure how people expect me to know that without telling me. At least explain that you need more information before downvoting a student. Jeeze. Thanks for the clarification Nathan.

Comment: @JerryCoffin I'm trying to assign parameters to an algorithm for the Traveling Sales man program. I need to take an unknown amount of user input and assign that input to either create a new city, or assign routes and costs for each city.

Comment: @ClaytonBrant _"That looks like perfectly good code to me."_ Believe me it isn't. It compiles, but certainly doesn't do what you want, or believe it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is really not much different than in Java. Here is an example of input handling with a `switch` statement. You can try it as an `if` clause as exercise.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
   std::string line;
   bool stop = false;
   while (!stop && getline(std::cin, line)) {
      switch (line[0]) {
         case 'C':
            // add to first array
            std::cout << "Case 'C': '" << line << "'\n";
            break;

         case 'A':
            // add to second array
            std::cout << "Case 'A': '" << line << "'\n";
            break;

         default:
            stop = true;
            break;
      }
   }
}
```

I skipped the part with inserting in an array and you should think about what you are allowed or supposed to use. Since you are not allowed to use the STL you should look into your class notes and problem statement what you have learned about arrays (dynamic and static ones).

Keep in mind, that you would not not use the STL in todays C++ applications.

Comment: If you want to extract only integer types this might not be the approach you are expected to do. As with all homework stuff, look what you learned in class and use these methods.

Comment: Unfortunately my class doesn't teach any C++ at all. I'm a transfer student and this is a mid tier class that focuses on algorithms. I'm expected to be an advanced C++ programmer already because thats the language the school uses, but my old school only used Java through my junior year.

Comment: You are in a tough spot then. Read up on a good Book, and take care, because there is a lot of garbage out there.

Answer (score 1):

For the moment I'm going to assume that the C++ code you have in the question doesn't matter much, and you're primarily looking for a reasonable analog of the Java code you included. In that case, C++ code intended to look similar to your Java code might look something like this:

```
std::string input;
std::vector<std::string> cityArray;
std::vector<std::string> routeArray; 

// ...

if (input.find('c') != std::string::npos) {
    cityArray.push_back(input);
}
else if (input.find('a') != std::string::npos) {
     routeArray.push_back(input);
}
```

If I were personally writing it in C++, I'd probably do something more like this though:

```
std::map<char, std::vector<std::string>> arrays;
// ...

arrays[input[0]].push_back(input);
```

Another possibility (that eliminates using `vector`) would be to use an `std::multimap` instead:

```
std::multimap<char, std::string> arrays;

arrays.insert(std::make_pair(input[0], input));
```

As to not being allowed to use the standard library: knock your teacher over the head with a clue stick. Without using the standard library you can't read any input or produce any output (just for a couple of examples) so for any practical purpose, your code can't do anything at all. You might as well just write every program as `int main() {}` and be done with it, because that's equivalent to essentially anything you can do without the standard library.

Comment: push_back is a member function of std::vector, but the title of the question ends "without using the STL".

Comment: @kfsone: it's using the `vector` from the C++ standard library, not from the STL (which is an entirely separate library, though it did form some of the basis for part of the design of some of the standard library).

Comment: @JerryCoffin He is a widely hated professor at my school. Everyone in my class thinks hes a bafoon, and there was an uproar at the beginning of the semester when he said we couldn't use the STL. Honestly I don't even know how or how to not use the STL. Anything that isn't Java confuses the heck out of me.

Comment: According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Template_Library) the `std::vector` class *is* part of the STL. `iostream` is not.

Comment: @ClaytonBrant if your class is about algorithms, it is only natural to ban the STL. Since all common algorithms are already implemented (well no graphs).

Comment: He did say we could use string and vector.

Comment: @Maikel: If you want to argue using the Appeal to Authority fallacy, it's best to at least start with a source that somebody *might* accept as authoritative.

Comment: @JerryCoffin Take it easy, I was just curious because I did not know for myself. Clayton clarified anyway and he is allowed to use `std::vector`. Since he is in an algorithm class I imagined he had to implement a dynamic array himself.